# Reference sorted list excel

Tags: excel, formulas, vba

I assume this is a super simple issue, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a workbook that contains 100+ company models, and a number of sheets that aggregates and treats the data. Im to create a report of the whole workbook and as such, want to create a number of indexes for the report.

To this end ive created a macro that assembles "sub portfolios" based on user input - i.e creating reports only containing companies in a certain sector or market, deleting all sheets not fullfilling the criteria.

The problem i have is that i have a list of companies and their revenue, which the macro fills and sorts from largest to smallest, which the index then references. When assembling a sub-portfolio and deleting certain sheets, the list contains a number of blanks, which i cant seem to get rid of, making the index full of blanks. Data->Filter->Remove blanks doesnt really help as it justs collapses the empty rows in the list.

I hope this is enough information to provide an answer, due to the nature of the project i unfortunately cannot provide the workbook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. We can help if you can provide the code and where in the code you are having issues. It would be difficult for anyone to rewrite the code and then come up with a solution

Comment: Why don't you just sort again after deleting sheets. Then the empty rows get sorted to the bottom